# Sum of two positive elements is positive in a $C^*$ algebra is positive

Tags: c-star-algebras

I think this is easy to see, using Gelfand Transform. Using the transform we can see $spec(a)=\{\phi(a)| \phi\in Spec(A)\}$ thus $spec(a+b)=\{\phi(a)+\phi(b)|\phi\in Spec(A)\}$ Now if both $a$ and $b$ are positive then clearly $\phi(a)$ and $\phi(b)$ sperately are non-negative and thus their sum is also.

I think this is a nice proof but I was wondering if there is a way of proving this without appealing to the Gelfand transform.

Comment: This depends strongly on how you define "positive".

Comment: @MartinArgerami Self-adjoint and the spectrum is real non-negative

Comment: It looks like you are assuming your $C^*$-algebra is commutative.  Is this the case?

Comment: @Sorfosh This proof only works when $a$ and $b$ are commuting, while the statement is more generally true.

Comment: @Aweygan you are correct. However, I would be interested to see how to prove this in the non-commutative case.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Could you provide a proof for the more general case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following characterization of positivity will do the trick.

Let $A$ be unital (otherwise consider the minimal unitization $\tilde{A}$ instead of $A$), let $x \in A$ be self-adjoint and $\lambda \geq \|x\|$. Then $x$ is positive if and only if $\|\lambda 1_A -x\| \leq \lambda$.

Proof. Consider the constant function $1$ and the identity function $id$ in $C(spec(x))$. Since $x$ is self-adjoint and $\lambda \geq \|x\|$ we have $spec(x) \subseteq \left[-\lambda,\lambda\right]$; moreover observe that $spec(x) \geq 0$ if and only if $\|\lambda 1 - id\|_{\infty} \leq \lambda$. Then by functional calculus we infer that $x$ is positive if and only if  $\|\lambda 1_A -x\| = \|\lambda 1 - id\|_{\infty}\leq \lambda$. QED

Now let's go back to the core discussion:

Let $x,y$ be positive elements of $A$, then $x+y$ is positive.

Proof. By the previous characterization we have in particular that $\| \|x\| -x \| \leq \|x\|$ and the same for $y$. Now $ \| \|x\| + \|y\| -(x+y) \| \leq \| \|x\| -x \| + \| \|y\| -y \| \leq \|x\| + \|y\|$. Again by the characterization above (with $\lambda = \|x\|+\|y\|$, where the triangle inequality guarantees that $\|x+y\| \leq \lambda$) we conclude that $x+y$ is positive. QED

Comment: Very interesting. You cannot use Gelfand transform on $A$ since it is not commutative. But $C^*(a)$ is so you can apply the Gelfand transform (and thus functional calculus) in the proof. Are my observations correct?

Comment: Yes, since $x$ is self-adjoint (in particular it's normal), then $C^*(x)$, which is generated by $x$ and $1_A$, is commutative and functional calculus holds.